# How to fix **__attribute__(( packed ))** error

Tags: gcc, centos, autotools, autoreconf

I cloned a copy of feng multimedia server, after running *autoreconf -i* in its directory, a *configure* script was created, but when I run this script, it gets stuck and exit with the following error:

```
 checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports __attribute__(( packed ))... no
 configure: error: unable to find how the compiler declares packed structures
```

Any idea of how I can fix such a problem ?

Output of *gcc --verbose* :

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4) (GCC)
```

---

Output of the *config.log* file:

```
| }
configure:7344: result: no
configure:7355: WARNING: POSIX realtime features not available
configure:7363: checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports __attribute__(( packed ))
configure:7385: gcc -std=gnu99 -c -g -O2 -Wall -Wwrite-strings -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wformat=2 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=return-type -DNDEBUG $
conftest.c:26: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'm4_ifnblank'
conftest.c:33:3: error: invalid preprocessing directive #Check
conftest.c:35: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'enableval'
conftest.c:36: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'else'
conftest.c:41:3: error: invalid preprocessing directive #Check
conftest.c:43: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'enableval'
conftest.c:47: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'if'
conftest.c:50: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'cat'
conftest.c:50: error: stray '\' in program
cc1: warnings being treated as errors
conftest.c:54: error: empty declaration
conftest.c:55: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'struct astructure'
conftest.c:55: error: size of array 'assert' is negative
configure:7392: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */


//...........OUTPUT TRIMMED.............//


#define _TANDEM_SOURCE 1
     #define HAVE_LIBEV 1
     _ACEOF
       m4_ifnblank(, )
else
  m4_ifnblank(AC_MSG_ERROR([libev not found, feng requires libev]), AC_MSG_ERROR([libev not found, feng requires libev]))
fi



# Check whether --enable-trace was given.
if test "${enable_trace+set}" = set; then
  enableval=$enable_trace;
else
  enable_trace="no"
fi


# Check whether --enable-tables was given.
if test "${enable_tables+set}" = set; then
  enableval=$enable_tables;
fi


if test "x$enable_tables" = "xno"; then


cat >>confdefs.h <<\_ACEOF
#define AVOID_TABLES 1
#define HAVE_DECL_STRERROR_R 0

configure: exit 1
```

Comment: Attach ``gcc --verbose`` output

Comment: I just edited the question and attached the output to it.

Comment: Just checked: gcc 4.4 (even 4.4.3) supports packed attribute. Please copy also exact compilation error, dumped in config.log

Comment: Thanks for your time really, well I just added the output that - I think - contains the error, and it gave me some idea about what's happening, I will try to fix it ... I guess something wrong with the code maybe ?

Comment: You omit the most interesting part -- subject code (conftest.c) of compilation. Attach it too. For now it is not clear what's wrong with enableval. I bet, that autotools somehow spoiled your build system. Than something wrong with autoreconf and your question should be retagged appropriately.

Comment: I edited the tags as you suggested, and I am trying to find the right snippet from the *config.log* file before I post it, cuz it's a large file

Comment: Dear Konstantin, I just uploaded the file to my drive because it's not possible to put all the output here, if you can take a look I'll appreciate it.
https://goo.gl/viDjXh

Comment: I just found out that passing this parameter to the gcc **-mno-ms-bitfields** may fix the problem, the only thing here is that i just don't know how or where i'll be able to pass it... any idea about that ? I may have to open a new thread for this one, the problem is with x64 architecture with the new version of gcc.

Comment: Possibly in CFLAGS. But I have no ideas about your config.log -- it seems raw part of configure script is inside conftest.c file under compilation (from line 1768 of your file madness begins). I never faced something like this, sorry. Double-check your configure script between 7363 and 7385 lines, and how conftest.c is being generated. It is not about compiler, or compiler flags at all.

Comment: Thanks for the great help and for taking the time to review the issue, I actually had to drop the code for another one, and ofcourse if I had a fix I would have posted it right away.